# iOS10 + Gradient stop working

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode8, uicolor, cagradientlayer

Just been moved to Xcode8 and iOS10, providing support for iOS10 to one of the application.

Figure out weird issue, suddenly Gradient is not working.

I found that after applying Storyboard (Storyboard changes in Xcode8) changes gradient not visible to views.

Xcode 7.3 - Gradient Views -

[image]

Xcode 8 - Gradient Views -

[image]

Also, If I replace Storyboard with old storyboard it shows gradient, So there is something wrong with new Storyboard.

There is no change in code:

```
[view setOpaque:NO];
view.layer.cornerRadius = 45;
view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:23.0/255.0 green:29.0/255.0 blue:36.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];

CAGradientLayer *gradient = [CAGradientLayer layer];
gradient.frame = view.bounds;

UIColor *color1 = [UIColor colorWithRed:33.0/255.0 green:39.0/255.0 blue:46.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];
UIColor *color2 = [UIColor colorWithRed:23.0/255.0 green:29.0/255.0 blue:36.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];
UIColor *color3 = [UIColor colorWithRed:14.0/255.0 green:20.0/255.0 blue:26.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];

NSArray *colorsArray = @[(id)color1.CGColor, (id)color2.CGColor, (id)color3.CGColor];

gradient.colors = colorsArray;
[gradient setLocations:@[@0.0, @0.35]];
[view.layer insertSublayer:gradient atIndex:0];
```

Let me know if any one figured it out.

**Edit:**

I didn't created new Storyboard, I just applied below changes as suggested by Xcode8

[image]

Comment: "Also, If I replace Storyboard with old storyboard it shows gradient" Then there is some crucial difference in the storyboards. Compare them and find it. Or use the old storyboard. (Why did you make a new one?)

Comment: Your code is OK. Run under debugger and check that view is not `nil`, and you actually applying the gradient. Set background in storyboard to something different, like magenta.

Comment: @matt - If app is created with Xcode 7.x and we open it to Xcode8 it make changes in old Storyboard, How ever there is way "Opens in Xcode 7.x". But it wont allow me to open Storyboard in that way, it always changes it to new one. Not created new Storyboard it is same

Comment: What changes? I didn't have to make a new storyboard for any of my apps when I upgraded to Xcode 8.

Comment: @matt: Please check edited question

Comment: Ok I understand and I figured out the problem!

Comment: If you want Answer in swift 3, ios 10 then I will post it @Kampai

Comment: @Jecky: No, not for now. anyways Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that there has been a change in the timing of layout. Therefore your code is now running too soon. You are saying

```
gradient.frame = view.bounds
```

But at this moment, view has zero bounds. So gradient has zero frame! That is why you cannot see it. You are doing layout code in `viewDidLoad`. This was always wrong and now you see why.

Move your code to `viewDidLayoutSubviews`. At that time, view has its real bounds. You will have to use a condition so that your code only runs once.

Comment: Oh Yes, I forgot about the frames!!!!!....it is working now. Thanks mate :)

Comment: I was wondering, Why it was working earlier in Xcode7.x, the code was in `viewDidLoad()` and It was working for iOS7, iOS8 and iOS9.

Comment: As I said: there has been a change in the timing of layout. You were lucky about the timing before, but you were making an assumption that was not required to be true. `viewDidLoad` is not a signal that frames have been applied. `viewDidLayoutSubviews` is.

Comment: Yes, thanks again. Noted